# String prints after bounds

Tags: c, arrays, string

I was printing out char from a string, and tried if I could to print the null character `strlen(str)`. But, the char before null was printed.

Then, I tried printing `strlen(str)+1`, it still prints the char before null.

Then,

index largely greater than bound, 1010101 --> Segmentation fault, as expected.

MAX -> 100   --> char before '\0'

MAX+1 -> 101 --> char before '\0'

MAX+5 -> 105 --> garbage

MAX+2, MAX+3, MAX+4 --> char before '\0'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str[101];
    scanf("%[^\n]",str);
    str[strlen(str)]='\0';
    printf("%c",str[105]);
}
```

The input condn is,
1=< str <=100

Input:

```
How are you?
```

Character var -> Char printed

str[strlen(str)-1] -> ?

str[strlen(str)] -> ?

str[strlen(str)+1] -> ?

str[100] -> ?

str[101] ... str[104] -> ?

str[105] -> garbage value that changes each time

Now, my question changed from why the null character is not printing, to, Why the char before null is printed? Even for values out of bounds??????

Edit:
printf("%s",str[strlen(str)]) returns -> (null)

Less than it gives `segmentation fault` and greater than it gives `(null)`

Comment: C have no bound checking, if you go out of bounds that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (which could seem to work, could crash your program, or [summon nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)). Don't do it.

Comment: By the way, considering that `strlen` works on null-terminated byte strings, by ***finding** the null-terminator*, doing `str[strlen(str)]='\0';` is not accomplishing anything.

Comment: `printf("%c",str[105]);` invoked *Undefined Behavior* -- anything can happen. Think of bounds-checking as *"training-wheels"*, C doesn't come with any.

Comment: I wanted to check end of string by checking if `code`str[i]=='\0'`/code`. 1)Now, how do I check end of string?

2) If strlen doesn't work, how do I place `\0` there? 

And, as strlen does return the length of the string, does that mean there is a `\0` there? 3) How did the null char get placed at `str[strlen]`?

Comment: Also, I placed a `\0` at str[strlen], **inside** the bounds. Why am I not able view the null character?

Comment: Print the address of each of the chars your printing, that will tell you if you're actually printing the same address each time or they're just the same value.

Answer (score 2):

As the other comments have said, this is undefined behavior. However it is possible that your program is actually reading and printing the character 104 bytes after the beginning of your string, and your terminal program does not know how to print that character so you end up with a `?` in the output.

What worries me more is your edit, `printf("%s", str[strlen(str)])`. Passing `%s` to printf indicates that you want it to take that argument as a pointer and dereference it. However `str[strlen(str)]` returns a char, not a char pointer. So you end up either passing in zero, which printf helpfully prints `(null)` for, or a number between 1 and 255, which is not a valid pointer and will cause the segmentation fault that you are seeing.